# How to create a real time stopwatch Windows Phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am currently creating a stopwatch app for windows phone 8.1, I am using the Stopwatch class but I cant seem to find a way to update the on screen timer continuously. Iv tried while loops to update the textblock as the stopwatch runs but this does not update until the method is over and causes a infinite loop.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!stopwatch.IsRunning)
            _sw.Start();

        while (stopwatch.IsRunning)
            this.sw.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DispatcherTimer`, set the `Interval` to say 1 second and in its `Tick` event update the `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GUI environments typically don't work the way you assume they would (keep updating the UI and listening for user interaction while your loop is executing). You should take a look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx) - it is about WPF rather than Windows XAML, but the basics are the same.

At a high level, your app runs a continuous loop that does *something* like this:

1. Check for user input
2. Run event handlers
3. Update layout
4. Render new UI
5. Go back to #1

So if you run an endless `while` loop in Step 2, the UI is never updated and the app never receives the `Click` event for the **Stop** button. You have to do something like have a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) (as suggested by [@Igor Kulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581164/igor-kulman)) that periodically checks the value of the stopwatch and updates the UI.

I would recommend more than once per second though; using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33)` will give you 30 frames a second.